# Check if ordinal datetime is after the current datetime?

Tags: python

I am given a number like: `737556.5965277777`.

```
>>> datetime.timedelta(days=737556.5965277777)
datetime.timedelta(days=737556, seconds=51539, microseconds=999996)

>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 15, 36, 41, 711686)
```

How can I compare this with the current datetime to check whether it is after? Either get the current timedelta and compare those or convert it to a timestamp first, then compare.

Comment: I don't think you can. You're trying to compare two different datatypes here. timedelta is not the same as datetime. It's like comparing str and int. You just can't.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert the current datetime to an ordinal, and then compare the two. If the ordinal datetime is greater than the now() ordinal datetime, then it is after.

You can use datetimes toordinal()

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dt_now = dt.now()
ordinal_date = dt_now.toordinal()
print(ordinal_date)
```

Comment: Hi doesn’t toordinal() only return int days? This also needs to compare the decimals.

Answer (score 0):

The ordinal datetime is just a number of day starting with date 0001-01-01 (as day 1). So you can just add the timedelta (minus one day, to compensate for 0001-01-01 not being day 0) to that date:

```
yourdate = datetime.datetime(1,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=737556.5965277777 - 1)
```

and compare it to now:

```
if yourdate > datetime.datetime.now():
```

Note that `yourdate.toordinal()` returns the integer part of your initial number: 737556.